# Group by a column and then sum an array column elementwise in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Hi I have a pyspark dataframe in the form:

```
    CATEGORY    VALUE
0   A           [4, 5, 6]
1   A           [1, 2, 3]
2   B           [7, 8, 9]
```

I would like my output to be

```
    CATEGORY    VALUE
0   A           [5, 7, 9]
1   B           [7, 8, 9]
```

The actual dataframe is ~2billion records and each array is ~1500 elements so this needs to be as efficient as possible, I have tried expanding the array into columns and then groupby which worked fine on my sample but I need a more efficient solution for the full dataframe.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add whatever you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to achieve the desired output is using a `UDF` , which will work on row-wise manner.

#### Data Preparation

```
s = StringIO("""
category|value
A|4, 5, 6
A|1, 2, 3
B|7, 8, 9
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(s,delimiter='|')

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
            .withColumn('value',F.split(F.col('value'),',').cast(ArrayType(IntegerType())))

sparkDF.show()

+--------+---------+
|category|    value|
+--------+---------+
|       A|[4, 5, 6]|
|       A|[1, 2, 3]|
|       B|[7, 8, 9]|
+--------+---------+

root
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

#### Element Wise Aggregation - UDF

```
@F.udf(returnType=ArrayType(IntegerType()))
def custom_arr(inp):
    
    res = np.array(inp)

    return res.sum(axis=0).tolist()


sparkDF = sparkDF.groupBy('category')\
                 .agg(F.collect_list('value').alias('value'))\
                 .withColumn('final_arr',custom_arr(F.col('value')))

sparkDF.show(truncate=False)

+--------+----------------------+---------+
|category|value                 |final_arr|
+--------+----------------------+---------+
|A       |[[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]|[5, 7, 9]|
|B       |[[7, 8, 9]]           |[7, 8, 9]|
+--------+----------------------+---------+
```